# how to get the root ancestors in a hierarchy query using oracle-10g?

Tags: database, oracle, tree, oracle10g, root

the table is very simple,pid means the parent id,and cid means the child id.And there may be more than one trees in the table.So my question is:
knowing ***several*** cid,how can we get the root ancestors
here is an example

**pid**  **cid**
1 2
2 3
3 4
5 6
6 7
7 8

given cid = 4 or cid = 8,I want to get their root ancestors whose pid is 1 ro 5
finally,I'm using an ***oracle 10g***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select 
  t1.cid,
  connect_by_root(t1.pid) as root
from 
  your_table t1
  left join your_table t2
    on t2.cid = t1.pid
where t1.cid in (4, 8)
start with t2.cid is null
connect by t1.pid = prior t1.cid
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1585a/3)

Comment: all the data is saved in a single table, so join is not intended to be used

Answer (score 7):

In a a database environment the foreign keys at the top level will most likely be nulls like so:

```
| pid  | cid  |
|------*------|
| null |  2   |
|  2   |  3   |
|  3   |  4   |
| null |  6   |
|  6   |  7   |
|  7   |  8   |
```

So I'd recommend using something like:

```
select connect_by_root(t1.cid) as startpoint,
       t1.cid                  as rootnode
  from your_table t1
 where connect_by_isleaf = 1
 start with t1.cid in (8, 4)
connect by prior t1.pid = t1.cid;
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/af6e3/1)