# Repeat a column value for multiple records with different IDs in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I am using Oracle 12c.

I have an Oracle table that is hierarchical where I would like to use the short name of the parent node (i.e. `start with parent_node_is is null`)
for all children nodes that belong to that parent.

For instance: Table Name: `nodes_tab`

```
NODE_ID    SHORT_NAME     PARENT_NODE_ID
---------- -------------- --------------
1          Parent Node-1  NULL
2          Child Node-2   1
3          Child Node-3   1
4          Child Node-4   2
5          Child Node-5   2
6          Child Node-6   4
7          Child Node-7   6
```

What I would like to achieve is to query the above nodes_tab for all node_ids but assign the short_name belonging to the parent node.

Ideally I just want to repeat the same name of `Parent Node-1` for the remaining node_ids from 2 down to 7 but unsure what the SQL query should be. I looked at LAG but it doesn't seem to do the trick.

Result I am after is:

```
NODE_ID    SHORT_NAME   
---------- -------------
1          Parent Node-1
2          Parent Node-1
3          Parent Node-1
4          Parent Node-1
5          Parent Node-1
6          Parent Node-1
7          Parent Node-1
```

Comment: Are you looking for `CONNECT_BY_ROOT(short_name)`? See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595850/how-to-get-the-root-ancestors-in-a-hierarchy-query-using-oracle-10g

Comment: What I am looking for is just a query that uses the short_name of the row where the `parent_node_id is NULL` and repeats this short_name against all other records where the `parent_node_id is NOT NULL`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hierarchically, your data looks like this:

```
SQL> with nodes_tab (node_id, short_name, parent_node_id) as
  2    (select 1, 'Parent Node-1', null from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'Child Node-2' , 1    from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'Child Node-3' , 1    from dual union all
  5     select 4, 'Child Node-4' , 2    from dual union all
  6     select 5, 'Child Node-5' , 2    from dual union all
  7     select 6, 'Child Node-6' , 4    from dual union all
  8     select 7, 'Child Node-7' , 6    from dual
  9    )
 10  select node_id,
 11         lpad(' ', 2 * level) || short_name as short_name,
 12         parent_node_id,
 13         connect_by_root short_name as root_node
 14  from nodes_tab
 15  start with parent_node_id is null
 16  connect by prior node_id = parent_node_id;

   NODE_ID SHORT_NAME                PARENT_NODE_ID ROOT_NODE
---------- ------------------------- -------------- -------------
         1   Parent Node-1                          Parent Node-1
         2     Child Node-2                       1 Parent Node-1
         4       Child Node-4                     2 Parent Node-1
         6         Child Node-6                   4 Parent Node-1
         7           Child Node-7                 6 Parent Node-1
         5       Child Node-5                     2 Parent Node-1
         3     Child Node-3                       1 Parent Node-1

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Note the `ROOT_NODE`, which is fetched by using `CONNECT_BY_ROOT` - it seems that you want that value for all `SHORT_NAME`s.

So: if we remove indentation and apply what we've seen above, along with appropriate `ORDER BY` clause, the final result is

```
SQL> with nodes_tab (node_id, short_name, parent_node_id) as
  2    (select 1, 'Parent Node-1', null from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'Child Node-2' , 1    from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'Child Node-3' , 1    from dual union all
  5     select 4, 'Child Node-4' , 2    from dual union all
  6     select 5, 'Child Node-5' , 2    from dual union all
  7     select 6, 'Child Node-6' , 4    from dual union all
  8     select 7, 'Child Node-7' , 6    from dual
  9    )
 10  select node_id,
 11         connect_by_root short_name as short_name
 12  from nodes_tab
 13  start with parent_node_id is null
 14  connect by prior node_id = parent_node_id
 15  order by node_id;

   NODE_ID SHORT_NAME
---------- -------------------------
         1 Parent Node-1
         2 Parent Node-1
         3 Parent Node-1
         4 Parent Node-1
         5 Parent Node-1
         6 Parent Node-1
         7 Parent Node-1

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Oracle 11GR2 and onward supports recursive CTEs (which are part of standard SQL).

So this works:

```
with cte (node_id, parent_id, short_name, lev) as (
      select node_id, coalesce(parent_node_id, node_id), short_name, 1
      from nodes_tab
      union all
      select cte.node_id, nt.parent_node_id, nt.short_name, lev + 1
      from cte join
           nodes_tab nt
           on cte.parent_id = nt.node_id 
     )
select *
from (select cte.*, row_number() over (partition by node_id order by lev desc) as seqnum
      from cte
     ) cte
where seqnum = 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6ad2980f16bf27e444b4873439e46968) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Oracle supports recursive sub-query factoring (which you call recursive CTE) starting with version 11g Release 2 which was released in September 2009. Almost **10 years** already.